# Arbitrary SQL with NSArray as Statement Argument

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, swift

I use [SQLite.swift](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift) and want to create an SQL statement like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM user WHERE id IN({userDtoIds})"
```

I did

```
let arr:[String] = // NSArray of Strings
let stmt:Statement = db.prepare("SELECT * FROM \(tableName) WHERE id IN(?)")
```

But `stmt.run()` does not allow `[String]` as argument.

**How can I use an NSArray as argument for an SQL Statement in [SQLite.swift](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift)?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the type-safe layer, you can use `contains()`:

```
table.filter(contains(ids, id))

// the above assumes this boilerplate precedes it:
let table = db["tableName"]
let id = Expression<Int64>("id")
let ids: [Int64] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] // e.g.
```

If you're using the raw SQLite3 API, it does not support arrays, so you'll need to format those yourself:

```
let template = join(", ", [String](count: count(ids), repeatedValue: "?"))
let stmt = db.prepare(
    "SELECT * FROM \(tableName) WHERE id IN (\(template))", ids
)
```